# How to handle similar names in wget?

Tags: wget, naming

I'm downloading so many images that their links are inside a file with the command:

```
wget -i file.txt
```

I suspect many of the files might have the same names. So I'm afraid they will be overwritten. is there anyway to make wget set sequential names to the file or handle similar names in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `wget 1.19.1`, what you're looking for is the default behavior. Files that have the same names will be numbered when a matching file is found.

Assuming that `file.txt` looks like:

```
http://www.apple.com
http://www.apple.com
http://www.apple.com
http://www.apple.com
```

The output of `wget -i file.txt` will be four files, named:

```
index.html
index.html.1
index.html.2
index.html.3
```